# if the union of three subspaces is a subspace, then one of the subspaces is contained in the union of the other two

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $K=\Bbb F_2$ and $V$ be a vector space over K.
Let $A,B,C$ be subspaces of $V$.

If $A\cup B\cup C$ is a subspace of $V$, then one of $A,B,C$ is contained in the union of the other two, ie one of the following holds:
$$A \subseteq B\cup C$$
$$B \subseteq C\cup A$$
$$C \subseteq A\cup B$$

How do I show if this is right or wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take $V = K^2.$ Then pick $A = \{(0, 0), (1, 0)\}, B = \{(0, 0), (0, 1)\},$ and $C = \{(0, 0), (1,1)\}.$ Thus $A \cup B \cup C = V$ is a subspace, but none of your inclusions hold.

Comment: Thank you! Simple but clever. Is the answer still the same if  1+1≠0 applies in K?

Comment: @Mathisnothealthyforu The theorem is true in characteristic 0.

Comment: @Mathisnothealthyforu More generally, looking at my argument, it's true if $K$ is any infinite field. I believe that with some work one could probably find a way to construct a counterexample to the finite field case.

Comment: @Michael i think it's true if char K $\neq$ 2.

Comment: @cineel Ah, actually I think it's true for any field except $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$ Take a field with three or more distinct elements, say $0, 1, x.$ Suppose you have a counterexample to the theorem. Pick $a\in A, a\not\in B\cup C$ and similarly choose $b.$ Then $a+0b, a+1b, a+x b$ all lie in $A\cup B\cup C$ since that union is a subspace. But none of these lie in $B$ (since $a\not\in B$), and $a+b, a+xb$ cannot lie in $A$ (since $b\not\in A$). Thus $a+b, a+xb$ in $C,$ but $x\neq 1$ then implies $(x-1)b\in C$ so that $b\in C,$ a contradiction. Thus this only fails over $\mathbb{F}_2.$

Comment: This was essentially the same argument I knew for infinite fields, but I didn't realize I could tweak it slightly to only need 3 scalars instead of infinitely many.